# Migrate Ionic from Cordova to Capacitor Storage

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, storage, capacitor

I currently have a Ionic Cordova App in the Playstore that uses the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin. Now I want to switch to Capacitor. Unfortunately I cannot use the storage plugin anymore with Cordova and need to switch to the storage plugin of Capacitor. This would work fine, but the Capacitor Plugin capacitor-data-storage-sqlite automatically adds SQLite.db to the database name.

For example my db file is appDb and if I try to use it with the capacitor plugin using appDb as Name, the plugin trys to use the file appDbSQLite.db and the db schema is also different.

So now I thought, ok I read my old sqlite file with sql querys and then write the values to the capacitor store. Now the problem is, that also the sqlite capacitor plugin @capacitor-community/sqlite appends SQLite.db to the filename, so I am not able to read the values from my appDb file.

Now I thougt, ok I copy my appDb file to appDbSQLite.db, to read the values, with sql queries, but unfortunately, I am not able in any way to copy the database file with the capacitor Filesystem api. I always get the error, that the file does not exist. My appDb file is in the database folder of the app.

Has anybody experienced similar issues, or can tell me, how to copy the database file with capacitor?

I highly appreciate any help with this =)

Comment: Have you found a solution here?